# Update existing issue field data in JIRA using rest api

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin, jira-agile, jira-rest-java-api

I have created a rest api to access an issue in JIRA. If I edit value of a field and save it using a button click, how to update the new value in that corresponding issue replacing the old value?

I have viewed the following links regarding editing and updating issues, but do not have idea how to access them.

1. [Editing issue](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-edit-issues?_ga=2.106053575.533932143.1505297158-784599446.1503469673)
2. [Updating issue](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/updating-an-issue-via-the-jira-rest-apis?_ga=2.106053575.533932143.1505297158-784599446.1503469673)

Can anyone help me with a basic example for updating values in an issue?

Comment: Your description is unclear. Are you updating the value in Jira or in a separate GUI from which you want to then update the Jira issue? You say that you are created a rest api, but I think that what you mean is a REST client that calls the Jira REST API.  You need to provide more information to enable an answer.

Comment: Yes, I have to edit an issue in my JIRA plugin and update them in JIRA issue using PUT method in ajax. I used this code given in this link [code1](https://jsfiddle.net/7g7jvvLx/) this works fine for GET method, but does not work for POST method.

Comment: So, now Iam using trying this below code to use GET and POST methods, as coded [here](https://jsfiddle.net/04o76tu6/) but I get the error - "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://localhost:' is therefore not allowed access." Finally, how can I edit and update the description field of an existing issue in JIRA. Or is there any way to overcome this error?